# Can an Arduino Pro Micro act as a USB hid and usb host device at the same time?

Tags: arduino, usb-device, usb-host

I know that the Pro Micro can act as a HID device.

As far as I understand the Pro Micro can also act as a USB Host using a usb-host adapter (shield) - right?

Now can the pro micro be both a device and a host by using 2 usb ports (the one from the pro micro for hid and the one from the usb-host shield for usb-host)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, yes. The usb host shield off loads some of the usb logic, freeing up the microcontroller to do other things. But both the host shield and the usb hid v-usb code are processor intensive, and you may find it difficult to do both host and peripheral at the same time due to memory and code space issues as well as strict timing requirements . Your welcome to try though.

Comment: A pro micro has native hardware USB, it does not need V-USB